# Javascript inside an html file

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an .html file that displays a webpage and i would like to tabs to be able to go to another .html file I have. how can i make a link on my page go to another file I have?
And another question, in the file I want to link, i have a javascript script that i would like to give an output. (Its an advanced version of Rock paper Scissors and i want it to say if i won or not.) what can i use to get an output. return(bla bla bla) doesn't do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link src="link.html">
    <style type="text/css">
.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Canada_goose_flight_cropped_and_NR.jpg');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: Shift, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.learn-more {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: Shift, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}
.neighorhood-guides {

    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}
.neighborhood-guides h2 {
    color:#393c3d;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.neighborhood-guides p {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
</style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class= "pull-left">
          <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class= "pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">

        <h1>Your Claculations Fast and Easy Than Ever Before!</h1>
        <p>Choose between 4 different calculators!</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="neighborhood-guides">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Calculators</h2>
            <p>We have four calculaotors that you can choose from:</p>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a src="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Trigonometry_triangle.svg/288px-Trigonometry_triangle.svg.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Trigonometry_triangle.svg/288px-Trigonometry_triangle.svg.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Trigonometry_triangle.svg/288px-Trigonometry_triangle.svg.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Trigonometry_triangle.svg/288px-Trigonometry_triangle.svg.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Trigonometry_triangle.svg/288px-Trigonometry_triangle.svg.png"></a>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Trigonometry_triangle.svg/288px-Trigonometry_triangle.svg.png"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="learn-more">
      <div class="container">
        <div class= "row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Codecademy</h3>
            <p>Learn to code at <a href="codecademy.com">codecademy.com</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Other Sources</h3>
            <p><a href="#">Find Other Homework-Helpers here</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Contact us</h3>
            <p>Contact us at example@example.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="link.html">lol</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Th page i want to link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissor Lizard Spock</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

  </head>

  <body>
<script>
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?");
var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

if (computerChoice == 0){
    computerChoice = "Rock";
}else if (computerChoice == 1){
    computerChoice = "Paper";
}else if(computerChoice == 2){
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
}else if(computerChoice == 3){
    computerChoice = "Lizard";
}else if(computerChoice == 4){
    computerChoice = "Spock";
}

console.log(computerChoice);
console.log(userChoice);

var compare = function(choice1 , choice2) {
if (choice1 == choice2) {
        return ("It's a tie!");
    }

if (choice1 == "Rock") {
    if (choice2 == "Paper"){
        return("Paper covers Rock!");
    }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
        return("Rock crushes Scissors!");
    }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
        return("Rock crushes Lizard!");
    }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
        return ("Spock vaporizes Rock!");
    } else {
        return("Not Valid Answer")

    }
}

if (choice1 == "Paper"){
    if (choice2 == "Rock"){
        return("Paper covers Rock!");
    }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
        return("Scissors cuts Paper!");
    }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
        return("Lizard eats Paper!");
    }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
        return ("Paper disproves Spock!");
    } else {
        return("Not Valid Answer")
    }
}

if (choice1 == "Scissors") {
        if (choice2 == "Paper"){
            return("Scissors cuts Paper!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Rock"){
            return("Rock crushes Scissors!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
            return("Scissors decapitates Lizard!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
            return ("Spock smashes Scissors!");
        } else {
            return("Not Valid Answer")
        }
    }
    if (choice1 == "Lizard") {
        if (choice2 == "Paper"){
            return("Lizard eats Paper!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
            return("Scissors decapitate Lizard!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Rock"){
            return("Rock crushes Lizard!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
            return ("Lizard poisons Spock!");
        } else {
            return("Not Valid Answer")

        }
    }

    if (choice1 == "Spock") {
        if (choice2 == "Paper"){
            return("Paper disproves Spock!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
            return("Spock smashes Scissors!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
            return("Lizard poisons Spock!");
        }else if (choice2 == "Rock"){
            return ("Spock vaporizes Rock!");
        } else {
            return("Not Valid Answer")

        }
    }
};
compare(computerChoice, userChoice);
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

so in the second page, how do i get the return function to work?

Comment: Add something like `<span id="res"></span>`  before the script and change compare(...) to `document.getElementById('res').innerHTML=compare(...)`

Comment: When you say "tabs to be able to go to another .html file" do you mean asynchronously load them, or just link to them?

Answer (score 1):

These are relatively simple, or introductory questions so I am going to explain a bit and link a bit.

I am assuming you want the tabs to link directly to another file on your same website, based on the contents of the question posted. With this assumption, it's rather simple to link using a relative, or fully qualified path to the file. Assuming your other pages are "page1.html" and "page2.html":

```
<a href="/page1.html">Tab</a>
<a href="/page2.html">Tab2</a>
```

These are root-relative paths, denoted by the forward slash at the front. If these files are in a sub-directory, but the same directory as the page linking to them, or a sub-directory to the page linking to them, you can do a document-relative link:

```
<a href="page1.html">Tab</a>
<a href="subdirectory/page2.html">Tab 2</a>
```

These links start at the same folder the current page is in and look within that folder for the file, or another folder with the file, in the case of Tab2.

Check out these examples/descriptions: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/hyperlinks.html

Explanation of Hyperlink element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Another small tutorial on hyperlinks: http://html.net/tutorials/html/lesson8.php

As for the output of the Javascript, there are a few changes I would make.

1. Move your script into the head. It's always best to define your script either in the head. You want to define the functions before they are called.
2. You can define the prompt and first choices as a function themselves.
3. You could actually do all of this in one function, but in my example below, I kept the compare separate.
4. For the most basic output, put a script in the body and call document.write to output the return value.

Code example for what I am referring:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissor Lizard Spock</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rockPaperScissorsSpock() {
        var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard or Spock?");
        var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

        if (computerChoice == 0){
            computerChoice = "Rock";
        }else if (computerChoice == 1){
            computerChoice = "Paper";
        }else if(computerChoice == 2){
            computerChoice = "Scissors";
        }else if(computerChoice == 3){
            computerChoice = "Lizard";
        }else if(computerChoice == 4){
            computerChoice = "Spock";
        }
        return compare(computerChoice, userChoice);
    }

    var compare = function(choice1 , choice2) {
        if (choice1 == choice2) {
            return ("It's a tie!");
        }

        if (choice1 == "Rock") {
            if (choice2 == "Paper"){
                return("Paper covers Rock!");
            }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
                return("Rock crushes Scissors!");
            }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
                return("Rock crushes Lizard!");
            }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
                return ("Spock vaporizes Rock!");
            } else {
                return("Not Valid Answer")

            }
        }

        if (choice1 == "Paper"){
            if (choice2 == "Rock"){
                return("Paper covers Rock!");
            }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
                return("Scissors cuts Paper!");
            }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
                return("Lizard eats Paper!");
            }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
                return ("Paper disproves Spock!");
            } else {
                return("Not Valid Answer")
            }
        }

        if (choice1 == "Scissors") {
                if (choice2 == "Paper"){
                    return("Scissors cuts Paper!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Rock"){
                    return("Rock crushes Scissors!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
                    return("Scissors decapitates Lizard!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
                    return ("Spock smashes Scissors!");
                } else {
                    return("Not Valid Answer")
                }
            }
            if (choice1 == "Lizard") {
                if (choice2 == "Paper"){
                    return("Lizard eats Paper!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
                    return("Scissors decapitate Lizard!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Rock"){
                    return("Rock crushes Lizard!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Spock"){
                    return ("Lizard poisons Spock!");
                } else {
                    return("Not Valid Answer")

                }
            }

            if (choice1 == "Spock") {
                if (choice2 == "Paper"){
                    return("Paper disproves Spock!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Scissors"){
                    return("Spock smashes Scissors!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Lizard"){
                    return("Lizard poisons Spock!");
                }else if (choice2 == "Rock"){
                    return ("Spock vaporizes Rock!");
                } else {
                    return("Not Valid Answer")

                }
            }
    };
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(rockPaperScissorsSpock());
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

These are fairly basic approaches, and I would definitely look into some online information, including some walkthroughs, for Javascript and HTML.

MDN is a good resource to start with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

As a side note, I purposely made only minor changes to the script.

```
var compare = function(choice1 , choice2) { ... }
```

is a perfectly valid way to define a function, especially within a namespace or object, but you could just define it the way I did with

```
function rockPaperScissorsSpock() { ... }
```

And though I have never used the site, there seems to be a number of topics for learning Javascript here: http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/

And there may be more complete or valid walkthroughs available online also for free.

Answer (score 0):

To link to another page, just use

```
<a href="URL or relative path">Some Text</a>
```

In the second file you need to declare the variable when you call the function, so you should change

```
var compare = function(choice1 , choice2) {
```

to

```
function compareChoices(choice1 , choice2) {
```

and change

```
compare(computerChoice, userChoice);
```

to

```
var compare = compareChoices(computerChoice, userChoice);
```

`compare` then should be the string that you returned

Comment: i know the script works, but it won't give the output in the browser.